# Which is better for checking previous object in list?

Tags: java

I have a for loop which loops through a list and builds and object, I needed to check the previous object with the one i'm building...which way is better?

This way?:

```
    String lastDirection= "";
    List<Stages> stages = new ArrayList();
    for (Object object : results) {
        Vector result = (Vector) object;
        Stages stage = new Stages();
        stage.setStage(result.get(0).toString());
        stage.setDirection((String) result.get(1));
        stage.setStageName((String) result.get(2));
        if(!stage.getDirection.equals(lastDirection))
            stages.add(stage);
        lastAtco = stage.getDirection();
    }
    return stages;
```

Or This way?:

```
    List<Stages> stages = new ArrayList();
    for (Object object : results) {
        Vector result = (Vector) object;
        Stages stage = new Stages();
        stage.setStage(result.get(0).toString());
        stage.setDirection((String) result.get(1));
        stage.setStageName((String) result.get(2));
        if (stages.size() >= 1 && stages.get(stages.size() - 1).getDirection().equals(stage.getDirection())) {
        } else {
            stages.add(stage);
        }

    }
    return stages;
```

I can see how one looks better than the other...but which one would be more efficient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The former would definitely be more efficient.

In the latter case, you "forget" a local variable that you have available (by letting it go out of scope), and then on the next iteration get it back by calling `stages.get()`.  There's no way that the `get()` call will be as cheap as simply referencing the `lastDirection` variable.

Comment: I see what you mean. I didn't think about that lol.